# What are the jumps of an Ito transformed semimartingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $f\in C^2$ and $(X_t)_{0\leq t}$ be a semimartingale.

We know from Ito's Formula 
$$
f(X_t) = f(X_0) + \int_0^t f'(X_{s-}) dX_s + \int_0^t f''(X_{s-}) d[X^c,X^c]_s + \sum_{s\leq t } ( \Delta f(X_s)  - f'(X_{s-} ) \Delta X_s)
$$

Now, this is a bit an awkward question, I guess I don't completely understand how to interpret the very last term.

I'm wondering what $\Delta f(X_t)$ is? I know that 
$$
\Delta  \int_0^t f'(X_{s-}) dX_s = \ f'(X_{s-}) \Delta  X_s 
$$
but what will the contribution from the last sum be? I guess what I can't seem to figure out is exactly what
$$\sum_{s\leq {t-} } ( \Delta f(X_s)  - f'(X_{s-} ) \Delta X_s)$$ should mean.

Comment: $\Delta f(X_s)=f(X_s)-f(X_{s-})$. [A better notation would be  $\Delta f(X)_s$.]